# how to generate a maze using a binary matrix representation?

Tags: matrix, binary, depth-first-search, maze

I'm suppose to generate a maze using a binary matrix
when a 0 represents empty cell
and 1  a wall

I tried to use the DFS algorithm, the problem is the DFS refers to cells and walls between them(each cell has at most four walls)

" then selects a random neighbouring cell that has not yet been visited. The computer removes the 'wall' between the two cells and.."

I don't understand to analogy to the representation I've been asked to implement

anyone has any idea?

Comment: Can you post what you've got so far?

Comment: I'm absolutely in the beginning, I have a Maze3dGenerator interface, and I'm working on concrete classes to implement it, I have a maze3d class

Comment: which contains a 3d binary array, I'm kind of stuck in understanding the analogy

Answer (score 1):

When asked to make a grid, I'd start by making a multi-dimensional array.
Have the outer array contain each row of your grid, and each nested array be the columns.
Depending if each cell needs to remember being visited, each slot of the array can contain a simple class or struct (depending on your language of choice). Else, they can simply contain an int or a bool.

A simple example could be:

```js
var grid = [
              [1, 1, 1],
              [1, 0, 1],
              [1, 1, 1]
           ];
```

Representing an empty cell in the middle, surrounded by walls.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to construct a pattern of cells, then build wall between them, but not when it has a edge of DFS tree.

Example DFS run (2D case, edge removed, can be inferred from order of nodes):

```
 O

 O
 O

 O
OO

OO
OO
(this branch is stuck so start a new one)
OOO
OO
...
OOO
OOO
OOO
```

Now construct the maze:

```
OXSOO
OXOXO
OOOXO
XXXXO
EOOOO

O -> cell
X -> wall
S -> start
E -> end
```

The wall can be either a block or just a plane, the topology is same.